# JUnit4: @Transactional removes data even before testcase is completed

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

In my Spring project I am running certain testcases using JUnit4. I use `@Transactional` to remove any changes made to the db during the testcases so that the new testcase gets the same initial db state. The problem is that in one of my testcases I insert some values in the db and later use them again in the same test. It looks like `@Transactional` removes the entries even before the test case is finished and as such my test doesn't run as expected. How can I resolve this issue?

It is something like this

```
@Test()
@Transactional
    // Add entries to db and do some asserts

    // Use those entries to do some more asserts
}
```

The second part doesn't work coz the entries are gone. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue?. Are you sure that the transaction rolled back before the methods returned?. Could there be a chance that one of your own methods called delete?

Comment: According to you code , it seems nothing to do with `@Transactional`

Comment: @TheLostMind I tried running the testcase seperately without Transactional annotation and the testcase ran as expected. I would not include Transactional but there are other testcases in the class which would be affected. I don't think any of my methods called delete, because in that case it wouldn't work without Transactional as well. Thanks !!

Comment: @passion I tried running the testcase seperately without Transactional annotation and the testcase ran as expected.So I guess it has to do with Transactional annotation. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

**You should only do this in test code, not in production code**

This is generally not a good idea to manipulate transaction manually, but it should be fine for a test, you just need to do this:

```
@Test()
@Transactional
    // Add entries to db and do some asserts
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()
    // Use those entries to do some more asserts
}
```

The method can be different.. but you can see the idea..